# Binding to Datagrid's ItemsSource collection properties instead of single items

Tags: c#, binding, silverlight-4.0, collections, datagrid

I'm confused while trying to bind some properties housed inside a collection rather than the properties of the elements.
I'm not even sure how to phrase it right... code might explain better: here are the types (not actual code, I've shortened it to the basics):

```
public class myType
{
    public int P {get;set;}
}
public class myTypeCollection : ObservableCollection<myType>
{
    public int Ptotal {get { return this.Items.Select(i=>i.P).Aggregate((c,t)=>t = t + c); }}
    public int Pmin { get { this.Items.Min(i => i.P); } } //concept
    public int Pmax { get { this.Items.Max(i => i.P); } } //concept
}
```

They're being used in a templated control, whose XAML looks like this:
(adding comments to make it as clear as i'm able to)

```
<!-- myGridObject = new myTemplatedControl(); -->
<!-- myGridObject.DataContext = new myTypeCollection(); -->
<!-- NOTE: collection obviously is NOT empty in the real code -->
<sdk:DataGrid ItemsSource={Binding DataContext}> 
    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Width="Auto">
        <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
            <Style TargetType="sdk:DataGridColumnHeader">
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate>

                            <!-- ?????? write out Ptotal in the header of the column ??????? -->
                            <!-- This throws a binding-related ArgumentException -->
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ???? Ptotal ?????}" />

    <!-- closing tags cut off -->
    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding P}" />
    <!-- closing tags cut off once more-->
```

`{Binding P}` works as expected, since `P` is a property of the items, but how do I access the collection's properties like `Ptotal`, `Pmin`, etc. ?

Thanks for taking the time to read this. If any info is missing just point it out and I'll post it.

Comment: Retagged to clarify it's Silveright 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the customer changed his mind about the grid headers, he doesn't want total displayed in the header anymore.

By the way, I must have tried 20 different approached including patching in various types of converters but I haven't been able to accomplish this not-as-simple-as-it-looks-apparently task.

Thanks again for the nonetheless interesting suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

So you need the collection object as your binding source.

You need these:

[RelativeSource MarkupExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743599.aspx)

[Binding.RelativeSource Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.relativesource.aspx)

Something like this (not tested):

```
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
AncestorType={x:Type myTemplatedControl}}, Path=DataContext.Ptotal}" />
```

If the DataGrid is inside your custom `myTemplatedControl`. It not totally clear for me what is myGridObject exactly. The main idea is:

As the MSDN documentation says: Binding.RelativeSource `Gets or sets the binding source by specifying its location relative to the position of the binding target.`

If you stuck with the x:Type extension, here is a link about it, so you can use it with your custom control:

[X:Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753322%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Another approach is if you name your container element (where your collection is the datacontext), then you can set that element as the binding source:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=yourElementName, Path=DataContext.Ptotal}" />
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm giving a shot to the "another approach", looks just right.

Comment: Code doesn't want to comply today: elementName approach has solved the exceptions but textblock remains blank. Gonna tweak more. As to clarify, `myGridObject` is the name of the templated control in the "main" application

Comment: check binding exceptions in the output window of VS while debugging the application. is there any binding exception?

Comment: I just tried your first approach, visual studio complains about `AncestorType` just as it did for the other answer's suggestion. I'm thinking about dropping the ball and make up a bunch of dependency properties to handle the headers independently ...

Comment: what version of silverlight do you use? RelativeSource does not exist in version 4. but you should be okay with the ElementName solution. Probably the binding path is not correct. you should see binding exceptions in the output while debugging

Comment: Uhm .. `RelativeSource` works perfectly fine if used for example like this `{Binding <Property> RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}` (this picks up a dependencyproperty from the templatedcontrol itself from inside its template, I use it extensively). Visual Studio doesn't show any exception in the output window, but I'm facing the Just-In-Time window with a `InvalidOperationException`... A coworker suggested a converter approach, trying this now...

Comment: Forgot to mention, it's SL4 i'm using (upgrade to 5 is not an option because of stubborn customer)

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that the DataGrid is bound to the collection, and each row is bound to an  individual item, not the collection.  You need to gain access a level up the chain (back to the collection itself).

If you're running Silverlight 4+ you can use a relativesource.  For instance:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=sdk:DataGrid, AncestorLevel=1}, Path=DataContext.Count}"
```

Otherwise perhaps create a static access to the context to access it via the binding `Source`

Comment: `AncestorType` and `AncestorLevel` don't seem to exist on the type `RelativeSource`, unfortunately the code as-is won't compile.

Comment: I think that only works in Silverlight 5, can you upgrade your project?

Comment: Unfortunately customer doesn't want to update the runtimes due to who-knows-why. Thanks for the suggestion anyway, I'll keep it in my own little snippet repo for future reference.